# Writing a function that returns an array of the intersect of two arrays in matlab?

Tags: matlab

**Question:**

**Write a function called intersect that accepts two 1-dimenstional arrays called A and B and return an array that contains the intersection of A and B**

**The way I did it:**

```
function C = intersect ([A,B])

For i=1:length(A)

    n=0

    While (n>length(B))

        n=n+1;

        If A(i)=B(i)

        C(i)=A(i)

        End

    End

End
```

**Is my solution Perfect?**

Comment: That's quite broad. Does your solution work as you expect? Do you want alternative solutions that may be simpler/faster? And btw, [intersect](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) is a built-in Matlab function so you might want to slightly change the name

Comment: Have you tested that function? I doubt it works as I can see at least two errors. Also what do you mean by 'intersection'? Your code only returns values that appear in both arrays at the same position. Is this what you really want? What if the same value appear in both arrays in different places? Would that be an intersection or not?

Comment: @PetrH I dont have matlab software to test it. OH yes u make a very good point, I didn't take into account that.

Comment: @Benoit_11 Thank you very much. Im making the changes and rethinking this.

Comment: No problem! A few points to consider: 1) Keywords `if`, `for`, `while` and `end` must be written with lower-case letters. 2) You might want to use `ismember` and `unique` to help you.

Comment: You also want to use == for comparison instead of =. Currently your inner loop doesn't execute ever as well. Why not use another for loop inside with a different loop variable? Then you can compare all A(i), B(j) combinations. In addition, you assume A is always the same size as B? Do you also intend for C to contain zeroed entries?